# eclipse pdt zend debug install error

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework

i have downloaded Eclipse PDT 3.0.x All In One. when i try to install zend debugger (http://downloads.zend.com/pdt) i get following error:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=pdtProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.zend.php.debug.debugger,5.3.18.v20110322
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.zend.php.debug.debugger.win32.x86,5.3.18.v20110322
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.zend.php.debug_feature,5.3.18.v20110322

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because somehow their metadataRepository is screwed up.

I solved this problem as follows, in my case ubuntu 11.04 and eclipse indigo, should work the same way for Windows. This solution requires a bit of work though and is a bit tricky. 
(As soon as they update their repository, this should not be necessary anymore)

(1) create a new local folder on your system at [pathName] (absolute path on your local machine).

(2) create two more folders:
[pathName]/plugins
[pathName]/features

(3) From this source location :  http://downloads.zend.com/pdt/ . Download the corresponding two plugins and the one feature and put them into the corresponding local folders

(4) Download also the content.xml and artifacts.xml and put them into [pathName].

(5) Edit the file [pathName]/content.xml, and replace the  section. Here is an excerpt, replace [pathName]

```
<references size='1'>
    <repository uri='file:/[pathName]' url='file:/[pathName]' />
</references>
```

(6) In eclipse: Help -> Install New Software -> Available Software Site -> Add
location : browse to and select [pathName].

(7) select the debugger, confirm approval of license, warning on security.

Done.

This was all a bit of a pain to get it right. If you still get errors, please verify the content.xml references, and that the right plugins the right feature *for your system* are in the subfolders. I am not supporting this, but it did work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "... replace *the* section" which section? I find a section called <references size='2'>, with two repositories inside, but replacing this won't work.

Comment: Yes, <references size='2"> should become <references size='1'>. Inside there should be one repository element as shown in step (5). This will work if you replace [pathName] with the correct local path on your the system where you are trying to install it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this URL in Eclipse: http://downloads.zend.com/studio-eclipse/updates/8_0/ (it is in the list, but is not selected by default, at least in 3.7.2, so you can just go to Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites and select it).

Select Zend Studio Features > Zend Debugger Feature from the list of available software.

It works.